# Confluence page displays error "We couldn't display your content Refresh the page and try again" when try to use myConfluence.content.id.get function

Tags: node.js, confluence-rest-api, npm-package

I tryed to use npm package @datafire/confluence to update confluence content by confluence.content.id.put({
but gets error in the confluence page.
"We couldn't display your content Refresh the page and try again if the problem persists, contact Atlasian support".
why the confluence page displays this error?

here is the code

```
 htmlStatics = "<html><a href=\"https://eps.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SE/pages/1049657802/UI+Backup+Reports\" data-linked-resource-id=\"1049657802\" data-linked-resource-version=\"1\" data-linked-resource-type=\"page\">UI Backup Reports</a><br> </br>" +
        "<img src='https://eps.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/1049657802"+imgdir+"1.png' id='reportImg' alt='Report screenshot' width='70%' height='90%'/> </html>";

try {
        let myNewData = await myConfluence.content.id.put({
          "id": recentContentID,
          "body": {
            "body": {
              "storage": {
                "value": htmlStatics,
                "representation": "storage"
              }
            },
            "version": {
              "number": currentVersion + 1
            },
            "status": "current",
            "title": "UI test Automation Report",
            "type": "page"
          }
        }
          , context)
        console.log("The change storage data using the async function: \n" + JSON.stringify(myNewData));

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error got from change storage is: " + error);
      }
```

Comment: any help ???????

Comment: The problem was in HTML code